# How to properly adjust Look Keo pedals

Tags: pedals

What is the best way to adjust the Look Keo pedals (mine are standard edition) so as to provide good grip, but with minimal wear on the cleats themselves? I use RED Keos.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question. There is a small screw that you adjust the tension with.

Or are you asking how hard the tension in the pedals should be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're never walking on the cleats and can track-stand at junctions and traffic lights they should almost never wear out.

There is minimal wear clipping in and out. The reds are 9 degrees of float before unclipping which may increase the wear though. I use the black cleats (0 degrees) and I wear out the bottom of the cleats through walking and stopping/starting long before I wear them out from riding. In fact, I'm on only on my second pair in 4 years.

Comment: Thanks! I should have got Black ones then. What are the disadvantages with black Keo though? Easy to unclip whilst riding?

Comment: I've never unclipped accidentally so I'd say no but I have 8 years riding clipless so it could also be a matter of being used to it.

Comment: The disadvantage of the black Keo is their need for precise angular adjustment along the longitudinal axis of the shoe. As a compromise, you can use the grey cleats.

Answer (score 1):

When cleat is seated in pedal, there is minimal wear on all surfaces - Pushing down produces a compression force, but the cleat is hard against the pedal's body.  When raising a foot the clipped ledge is also under compression.  At no point is there significant sliding friction between cleat and pedal as there is while walking.

I use knockoff-brand Keo compatible cleats with ~6 degrees of float.  They last between 6 and 12 months, and they work perfectly until something breaks one of the clips off, this is mostly standing on something not flat, like when carrying the bike down stairs at work from our first floor indoor bike parking room.

I always put the left foot down at lights, so that one always wears out first and its frequently at the toe end.   It would be possible to swap them, or save the less-used one for another month's wear, but cheap Wellgo cleats at $5NZ a pair are worth about the same as 2 gels, so its hardly worth bothering.   If cleats were $36 NZ a pair like proper Look branded ones I'd be more careful